# Change format in date picker (air date picker)

Tags: javascript, html, date, time

I am using Air date picker, How to change time format to 24h?
[http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/)

Only see 12h format in my case,
[image: here photo of my format]

Comment: Can you show us your code because by default that should be 24-hrs format only?

Comment: yes I want 24h format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove `aa` or `AA` in your time format [document](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/#opts-timeFormat)

```
<div class="datepicker-here" data-timepicker="true" data-time-format='hh:ii'></div>
```